# Strong Parameters, how to pass the required hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button from *Users index view* to  *Friendship controller*.
But I can't figure out how to correctly pass the hash, which is required by the *strong parameters*.

*Users index view:*

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= button_to 'Add friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => user.id), method: :post %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

*Friendship controller*

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:friend_id)
end
```

How can I pass the ':user' hash along with the ':friend_id' ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably best with the following:

```
def user_params
   params.permit(:friend_id)
end
```

---

**Params**

The *params* part of the system basically works by taking the `params hash` and "permitting" the relevant values based on it, as per the following...

When you submit a `form_for` (as this is built around an ActiveRecord object), you'll receive a params hash like this:

```
params => {
  "[Model]" => {
    "param_1" => "value",
    "param_2" => "value",
    "param_3" => "value"
  }
}
```

In this instance, you'll use the `require` tag in `strong_params`:

```
def strong_params
   params.require(:model).permit(:param_1, :param_2, :param_3)
end
```

--

The situation you have is that you want to use use a single "level" of params hash:

```
params => {
  "friendly_id" => "value"
}
```

In this case, you'll want to use the following:

```
def strong_params
   params.permit(:friendly_id)
end
```

---

**Logs**

The best way to get this working is to observe the params hash that you're dealing with.

You can view the logs and see the Params hash outputted each time you make a request to Rails - I would look at that, and determine the structure of your params hash in order to ascertain the type of `strong_params` method you should call